# How to build a "Image Store" in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm building an Image Store for my app, basically it's a singleton that manages images download and caching (two levels `NSCache` and Core Data).

I was wondering if I could use blocks instead of delegates, I mean, there can be multiple requests for the same image, I want to update all the pending requesters by "triggering" the block they provided on call.

Is it possible to store a block in an `NSArray` and call it when I downloaded the image? Does this make sense?

What if the block is then triggered when the calling object has been deallocated?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list of observers for an event then you should look at `NSNotification`s instead.

Every time an image is downloaded your singleton should do something like

```
NSDictionary *info = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      image, @"image", 
                      originalURL, @"imageURL",
                      nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"imageDownloaded" object:self userInfo:info];
```

and anyone interested in that image should receive a notification about it.

You can extend this pattern to include notifications about progress and failed downloads as well :)